Is there a function to style an entire row or column in the Excel package for Flutter apps
I'm using the Excel package to generate a xlsx file in my Flutter app. The package works well but when wanting to change the style of a cell in a row or in a column I only find the method to change a specific cell by row and column index.
I dont find that very practical if many of the rows are appended because the data is dynamic.
What I would like is to for example add a row and than change the styling for the cells in that row. If at leas there would be a function to get the last appended row that would help.
Does anybody know if there is a way to do this?
